# How to highlight multiple polygons at once based on feature properties value

Tags: leaflet, javascript

I am trying to figure out how to highlight multiple polygons/features based on the `feature.properties.NAME` value. My polygons are a bit broken up so they are separate features and using an `onEachFeature` function will only highlight the specific shape mouseover as opposed to all of them with the same name.

```js
// current function being used to highlight
function onEachFeature(feature, layer) {
  layer.on('mouseover', () => {
      layer.setStyle({
        weight: 4,
        opacity: 0.7
      });
    }),
    layer.on('mouseout', () => {
      layer.setStyle({
        weight: 1,
        opacity: 0.85
      });
    })
}
```

For example here is a sample [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/anwgture/10/). When mousing over a "SHAPE-A" polygon it should highlight the 3 (top, top left, bottom right) and mousing over "SHAPE-B" should highlight the 2 (right, bottom left).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible solution would be to use `mouseover` event processing function to store  name of the feature to global variable `highlightedName`. This name can be then used in the style function to set highlight style when name of the feature equals stored global name. Also `.setStyle` method has to be explicitly used to change the layer style when variable `highlightedName` is set.

Your code could then look something like this:

```
var highlightedName = null;

function mapStyle(feature) {
  var weight, opacity;
  if (feature.properties.NAME == highlightedName) {
    weight = 4;
    opacity = 0.7;
    }
  else {
    weight = 1;
    opacity = 0.85;
  }
  return({
    color: "#1890ff",
    weight: weight,
    opacity: opacity
  });
}

function onEachFeature(feature, layer) {
  layer.on('mouseover', () => {
    highlightedName = feature.properties.NAME;
    vectorLayer.setStyle(mapStyle);
  }),
  layer.on('mouseout', () => {
    highlightedName = null;
    vectorLayer.setStyle(mapStyle);
  })
}

var map = L.map('map', mapOptions).setView([0, 0], 3);

var vectorLayer = L.geoJSON(basemap, {
    style: mapStyle,
    onEachFeature: onEachFeature
  })
  .bindTooltip(function(layer) {
    return layer.feature.properties.NAME;
  });

map.addLayer(vectorLayer);
map.fitBounds(vectorLayer.getBounds());
```

Comment: this possible with vector grid .pbf files?

Comment: Not enough info to answer that. Post it as a separate question with all the necessary info.